# Is it possible to install windows 7 on a windows 8 computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I just bought a Samsung Ultrabook (series 9) with an AMD processor, that came with Windows 8 about 2 months ago, and unfortunately, I downloaded some stuff, and got a pretty bad virus, and the computer became super-slow. I tried an antivirus, but it didn't work, so I decided to reformat it and just get Windows 7, but the problem is that, I was able to uninstall the windows 8, and just can't seem to get Windows 7 installed?

Comment: in your bios, do you have UEFI secureboot settings enabled? if so, you may need to disable them in order to install win7. http://liliputing.com/2012/12/samsung-series-9-np900x3d-windows-8-ultrabook-review.html . what specific error are you getting from the install? can you boot from the win7 disk at all? also, does samsung provide win7 drivers for your model of laptop? if not, you may have to identify your hardware components, and try to find win7 drivers individually. Usually its better to get the drivers, and put them on a flash drive before you start your rebuild.

Comment: See above. You will need to change BIOS boot settings for win7's bootloader to work

Answer (score 1):

A factory image restore will be the fastest way to get your system back running. Anything more/less will most likely void the warranty of your 2 month old PC. See [Understanding downgrading rights](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=sLMLnUlmfw8) from Microsoft to help decide if you can/should downgrade or not...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can. Take it from me, a friend re-installed Windows 7 on his default Windows 8 machine and hasn't looked back since.

First, try wiping your laptop disk clean with a program such as Kill-disk. This will erase any trace of the virus from your disk. This is a must because it allows the disk to be completely clean for a fresh install. Then once the disk is completely erased and blank, Windows 7 should be able to be installed cleanly without any problems. Make sure you use a genuine windows 7 disk because there have been known problems with installing illegitimate versions of Windows.